# Language on react-native-bip39 seed phrase generate

Tags: react-native

I had added a chinese simplified and traditional json to wordlist folder, how can I tell it to generate seed phrase with specific language ?

https://github.com/novalabio/react-native-bip39

```
_generate12SeedPhase = async(callback) => { 
await bip39.generateMnemonic().then((mnemonic)=>{
  callback(mnemonic); // output is other language i want
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the json file into a variable and put it into a function, parameter.

```js
var DEFAULT_WORDLIST = require('./wordlists/cn.json')

_generate12SeedPhase = async(callback) => { 
await bip39.generateMnemonic(undefined, undefined,DEFAULT_WORDLIST).then((mnemonic)=>{
  callback(mnemonic); // output is other language i want
```

**generateMnemonic function in react-native-bip39**

```js
function generateMnemonic(strength, rng, wordlist) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    strength = strength || 128
    rng = rng || randomBytes

    rng(strength / 8, (error, randomBytesBuffer) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error)
      } else {
        resolve(entropyToMnemonic(randomBytesBuffer.toString('hex'), wordlist))
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also figure out the same way as you suggest. But thanks to your answer